# Use a type as a function Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a **Type** here to convert an ID to an object, I understand this allows personId as a string parameter and returns a Person/undefined.

```
export type FindPerson = (personId: string) => Person | undefined;
```

I have bunch of person IDs and would like to use this type to convert to Person objects. I tried this way but it didnt work, it returns a FindPerson object instead a Person object.

```
const person = { personId: "1923-01-01a" } as unknown as FindPerson;
```

Is there any way that I can re-use the type above to get a Person object by ID?

Answer (score 2):

The type you have just defines the **type** of a function. It doesn't define any code for an actual function. You can't use it to convert a string to a `Person | undefined` because it doesn't actually **do** anything, it just defines the type of something that would do something if you created one. Types don't exist at runtime (other than enums, which have some runtime presence). A *type* can't convert a value. (Types can convert types, but not values.)

You'll need to write a function that does the work of accepting a string and returning either a `Person` or `undefined`. For instance:

```typescript
const findPerson: FindPerson = (personId: string) => {
    // ...code to do the work...
};
```

Here's an example with context, though of course most of this is stand-in code for what your real code would be:

```typescript
// Placeholder
type Person = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
}

// Your type
/*export*/ type FindPerson = (personId: string) => Person | undefined;

// Stand-in for the actual person storage
const personStore: Map<string, Person> = new Map();
function addPerson(id: string, name: string) {
    personStore.set(id, {id, name});
}
addPerson("1923-01-01a", "Joe Bloggs");
addPerson("1924-01-01b", "Mohammed bin Ammar");
addPerson("1925-01-01c", "Constanza Alvares");

// The function
const findPerson: FindPerson = (personId: string) => {
    return personStore.get(personId);
};

// Using it
const person = findPerson("1923-01-01a");
console.log(person);
console.log(findPerson("1924-01-01b"));
console.log(findPerson("no-such-person"));
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAUBsEMGMFMAWB7SATeAnAUAFwJ4AO8EWAzsgHagC8oA3tqM6AJZoBcoZumrlAcwDcTFpWgBbeFx59BIgL7ZsIUAE1kAV0ygCxFQCp4AD0LJMuA2D0kAYvzThyVWqAAUxTBUoBJTt15+AQBKWgA+Ui8XAB9QTUoMADN+eDQRFTAAZVxoBIBaflBE811EEjhcTWhIUE9vAPNoAXhsWCoeWudKbPNpUABZaEIAHlkggBpI7wi6SngAdwGht2CRRPjYXFYXaDRHLrd2GUDBSfEpY7kQhlFmOqoezHgAOjJ4XEO0Sfp2M8l4BSrbBKXb7KKUNwAIgAjABOABMAGY8gAGaGo6HQSGTSEAKWQJAAQpBkAIBGRIUDQU5wVC4fCACwYjEAI2xoEh-WQiEkUjQoBZhQAghIJNBMJSRNSDjCEQBWZlo2DsyEAYXaOUoAC9oKAhZAAG7i+AUoEZUAAFTKRQ2WyorQ1RQcNO8XHsCRdLjoHi6fkuQVCNAijBYoCelUw1Hu3VwvWezQ+0b8QIU6VUAFUyEE2LgHZQOtHXMkPTL6ci0RisUC2vnUC8SQIfeDq+0688G25i2DvHSEUyK2i2cEW7XIPXSZ3nTLKMg8mRNLBEHlo5TVkA)

A type like your `FindPerson` is mostly useful when:

1. You want to defend against coding errors during maintenance, such as someone adding a parameter or changing the function so that it doesn't return the correct value. (Particularly useful with several functions presenting the same interface.)
2. You'll already have a function but the parameter names aren't as clear as they would be if you renamed them. For instance, in the above, we could have defined `findPerson` like this:

   ```typescript
   const findPerson: FindPerson = personStore.get.bind(personStore);
   ```

   Without the type annotation, the hint for the parameter would be `key` (inherited from the type of `Map.prototype.get`). But with the type annotation, it's the more-specific `personId`.